# Incorrect number of file hard links

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, error, repair

DiskUtility on Yosemite gave me this error message :

> Incorrect number of file hard links

I would like to repair my disk but i don't know if it will erase all my documents.

Can someone tell me if repairing the disk is going to format it too?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard link is a reference in a directory file that is the same inode ( reference in the file system) to another file in the same directory or a different directory). If one hard link is removed from the file system then the other(s) will not be removed. In any case, repairing a file system may cause loss of data. Attempt to backup before repairing the file system.